# Doing simple math with .css Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, variables, math

I'm very new to jQuery and the world of JS, so please pardon my ignorance.
I'm trying to get the width of the .grid-sarah so I can center content inside of it. Everythings working fine, except the (heightFix-30) does it not recognize that it's doing -30px not -30? also the var textIndent isn't working when I divide it by 4. I don't think showing my CSS and HTML is necessary let me know otherwise.

Script

```
 function squares(){
  var heightFix = $('.grid-sarah').css('width');
  var heightFixer = (heightFix-30);
  var textIndent = (heightFix/4); 
    $('figure.effect-sarah').height(heightFixer); //-30px off
    $('figure.effect-sarah h2').css('line-height', heightFix);
    $('figure.effect-sarah h2').css('text-indent', textIndent);
    // $('figure.effect-sarah h2').css('margin-left', '25%');
};

  squares();

$( window ).resize(function() {
  squares();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Use `console.log(myVar)` to debug your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.grid-sarah').css('width')` adds a `px` at the end.

Use `$('.grid-sarah').width()` instead.

`$('.grid-sarah').width()` will return the `width` in (int) pixels without adding `px` at the end.

So your function `squares()` becomes :

```
function squares(){
  var heightFix = $('.grid-sarah').width();
  var heightFixer = (heightFix-30);
  var textIndent = (heightFix/4); 
    $('figure.effect-sarah').height(heightFixer); //-30px off
    $('figure.effect-sarah h2').css('line-height', heightFix+"px");
    $('figure.effect-sarah h2').css('text-indent', textIndent+"px");
    // $('figure.effect-sarah h2').css('margin-left', '25%');
}
```

Comment: how do I add px to the end after implementing this? for the line-height css command, it doens't add pixels

Comment: I just mentioned your edited function, Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I can't upvote, but I did mark it as correct. Also I'm trying to dynamically calculate the width of each h2 and then subtract that from the width of the container and then / 2 and set that as text-indent so all text is centered without text-align center. can you help me with that?

Comment: Ask a new question if you have a new question.  (But why not use text-align: center?)